# Error On Page Because Of Firebug-Lite

Tags: javascript, firebug, firebug-lite

When i click Firebug's bookmarklet (Firebug Lite) on Internet Explorer .

[image]

There is an error on my page.

[image]

I can't solve this. Firebug Lite working all other websites, but doesn't working on my webpage.

You can check here : http://www.teknoblogo.com/yeni

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a facebook iframe in your html page, and IE restricts access of Javascript scripts to the document objects of frames that are from a different domain. (FireBug Light tries to iterate through all frames and load information about their stylesheets, etc.)

If you're debugging your own site, try to remove all external iframes and then load firebug light again. Otherwise, there may be a way to disable the restriction (by modifying IE's security settings) on your specific browser.