# javascript debugging in internet explorer

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, javascript

Assume,
There is a web project that work fine in IE8 and FF3+
but there is some java script error in IE7- and the only thing that you have to find the problem is just an error from developer toolbar in browser mode IE7 like this:

Expected identifier, string or number  Persons, line 135713438 character 9

and of course there is no line 135713438 and your English is very bad :D

So what can you do?

Comment: possibly same error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842459/error-on-page-because-of-firebug-lite

Answer (score 0):

You could try Firebug Lite:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: Note: Firebug Lite is used for IE development testing. It's meant to extend the excellent Firebug toolkit to IE.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MS Script Editor, free component of Microsoft Office XP/2003. Read this [article](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer) for more info about how to use it.