# IE7 and TinyMCE with Plone

Tags: tinymce, plone

In an out of the box Plone 4.1.4 (4113) on a windows server, some clientside problems occur on IE7 (I know...).

- Going to the main site: no problem
- logging in: IE raises a runtime error: Line 505: Expexted identifier, string or number
- Adding content: IE raises a runtime error: Line 505: Expexted identifier, string or number and gives a javascript error complaining that there is no "TinyMCE_config".

This function doesn't work:

- TinyMCE refuses to show it's controls and IE7 gives a Javascript error saying:

The institution is planning the move to IE8, but this is not finalized yet.

FF: no problem
Chrome: no problem
IE8: no problem

Any ideas (besides moving to a different browser...)?

btw: when trying out TinyMCE on their site, IE7 gives no errors at all...

Comment: +1 what happens if you remove all plugins from the configuration (plugins: '',)?

Comment: If you mean "Add-ons", when deactivating all products (from within sitename/prefs_install_products_form) : same thing.

Comment: no i mean plugins, tinymce plugins

Comment: Have you tried logging a Plone bug report?

Comment: @Thariama: I removed ploneimage and plonelink but this doesn't result in any improvement

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've just started using the software since 1.5 weeks,  the threshold towards filing a bug report is still rather high :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Bug report filed and [confirmed](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12812). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expexted identifier, string or number means the javascript has an unneeded colon (',') somewhere ( http://devharbor.blogspot.it/2011/10/ie7-and-error-expected-identifier.html )

To debug what it is, follow this guide: [javascript debugging in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842505/javascript-debugging-in-internet-explorer)

I've used http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite and it worked to find the problem :)

Comment: in this case it looks like there is an unneeded ',' at the end of a javascript parameter

Comment: I tried to edit the tiny_mce_init.js file and my site degraded to no visual style. The sunburst theme is no more :-) .  The steps I took were : 1. edit the file and remove the trailing comma 2. save 3. restarted the services 4. sav the error 5. ran buildout. 6. still saw the error... Maybe a new question but how do you edit a js - file under plone?

Comment: Tried it using a new site, and the IE7 tinymce problem is gone. Gladly granting you the answer... (edited the question a little since the problem regarding dropdown menus is not answered, will move this to another question)

Comment: I believe this is fixed upstream, but not released.  You may want to keep tabs on Products.TinyMCE on PyPI and github.