# tinyMCE editor bar not showing up

Tags: tinymce, plone

I'm running Plone 4.1.4 and when I try to edit a text area that used to display the tinyMCE editor all I get is a dialog box listing a dict of "valid elements".  I installed the kupu editor and that works fine, but I prefer tinyMCE.  Has anyone run in to this issue?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: di you check your server logs for errors already?

Answer (score 2):

Browser and version?  IE 9 has TinyMCE issues, and requires you to use a development release.

To get around it I had to install a version from github. If you have mr.developer, use:

```
Products.TinyMCE = git https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE.git branch=GSOC-3.4.x
```

Comment: It does not seem to be a browser issue because I get the same problem in IE, FF, Chrome, and Opera.  On my server I have two plone sites, both have identical settings but TinyMCE doesn't work on one.  The only difference I see is the version of TinyMCE is 1.2.10 on the site that doesn't work and 1.2.8 on the site that does.  I'll look into that some more.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this problem as well.  In my case I updated Plone 4.1.2 to Plone 4.1.4.  The rich widget will not show the TinyMCE editor when the content type has just been added.  But after saving the content type and then editing, TinyMCE would appear as expected.

The weird thing is that if you add a new Plone instance and then activate and add your custom AT content type.  TinyMCE would render fine on your text fields.

A work around that seemed to solve the issue is to go to portal_setup and on the upgrade tab, select Products.TinyMCE:TinyMCE to upgrade.  It would show that the profiles (version 3) on the ZODB and the filesystem are in sync.  You can downgrade by clicking on "show old upgrades" and running upgrade profile 1.1->2.  This worked for me but please try this on a development instance.

Answer (score 1):

This looks exactly like a problem I had a few days ago. Are you using IE7 or below?

Though I don't know if this is the right way to go (more experienced devs, please advise), this is what I did:

- (Assuming a windows box... )
- Stopped the plone services
- located the file on the filesystem called tiny_mce_init.js (in my case c:\Plone41\eggs\products.tinymce-1.2.10-py2.6.egg\Products\TinyMCE\skins\tinymce\tiny_mce_init.js)
- go to line 93 (in my case this contains:
  `media_strict: false,`
- remove the comma resulting in `media_strict: false`
- save the file
- restart the services

Looks at [Thariama's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889978/ie7-and-tinymce-with-plone).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with IE and FF). It looked like the archtype installation was the problem.

After changing the order unter "ZMI->portal_skins->Sunburst Theme" (putting tinymce above archetypes), TinyMCE worked.

(http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Tinymce-not-working-after-custom-type-is-installed-td7566873.html)