# TinyMCE Visual Editor not loading in Plone 4.3.11

Tags: tinymce, plone

There seems to have been a few similar questions, but none of the answers to those have helped me.

I have recently done an upgrade of an existing Plone site from 4.2.4 to 4.3.11, and Products.TinyMCE has been upgraded from 1.2.15 to 1.4.3. Content has been migrated successfully, but the visual editor does not show up on Archetypes TextField using RichWidget.

Javascript errors refer to failure to load:
/plugins/ploneimage/editor_plugin.js
/plugins/plonelink/editor_plugin.js

Now, I know these have been merged into plonebrowser in Products.TinyMCE version 1.3-beta1, but how do I get TinyMCE to "wake up" and use /plugins/plonebrowser/editor_plugin.js? There are no migrations to be done for TinyMCE in portal_setup.

Here follows a screenshot of the error in the console:

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFURM.png)

Comment: "failure to load" is an HTTP error loading the resource or you have a traceback? Can you edit the question providing it, or a screenshot of the error on debugger?

Comment: Thank you Luca. I have added a screenshot to my question. What TinyMCE should be loading, post version 1.3-beta1, is /plugins/plonebrowser/editor_plugin.js, but instead it is trying to load /plugins/ploneimage/editor_plugin.js and /plugins/plonelink/editor_plugin.js.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it, as far as I remember the proper solution is to run an upgrade step, will look for it.

Comment: Check if this is working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11152962/646005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Products.TinyMCE 1.3.x (latest 1.3.25).
The 1.3.x minor is Plone 4.3.x compatible.

[dist.plone.org/4.3.11](http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.11/) also points to a 1.3.x release

The 1.4.x is a Plone 5 compatibility release.
--> I assume this from the changelog entries :-)

EDIT:
You may also disabled some TinyMCE plugins. Please check if all plugins are still activated in `[SITE_URL]/portal_tinymce/@@tinymce-controlpanel` --> tab "Resource Types" --> field "Custom Plugins".

It should only contain `plonebrowser` as an entry. For making sure your config-modification is programmtically reproducable add a file named `tinymce.xml` in one of your custom add-ons' profile, containing these lines:

```
<object>
 <resourcetypes>
  <customplugins purge="False">
    <element value="plonebrowser"/>
  </customplugins>
 </resourcetypes>
</object>
```

Note that `purge=True` replaces the existing entries entirely, where `purge=False` will add the entries to the existing ones, which we want, because it could be, that more plugins have been installed and their entries should remain.

Removing entries via the tinymce.xml-config is not possible, AFAIK. It should be possible with a Python-script triggered of an upgrade-step or an add-on installation, yet I'd probably just remove `ploneimage` and `plonelink` manually, for that one time.

Comment: Thank you Mathias. I have tried version 1.3.25, but unfortunately I still get the same console error.

Comment: Are all tinymce plugins still activated? Check the TinyMCE control panel --> Plugins

Comment: Thank you very much Mathias! plonelink and ploneimage were still listed under custom plugins together with plonebrowser. Removing those fixed the problem. Using Products.TinyMCE 1.3.9 now, and issue is resolved. Thanks also for input from Lucca and alepisa!

Comment: @atblue That's great! You might want to accept the answer then, also :-)

Comment: @IdaEbkes Thank you very much for the Edit!! I was almost pointing at the right direction ;-)

Comment: @Mathias: Very welcome and thanks to you, that you're constantly giving friendly and helpful support for Plone-users!

Comment: @atblue: Ah, caused by your own custom add-on? That's an important feedback, to exclude it could have been a bug, thanks. BTW, an upgrade with a vanilla-site worked fine for me.

Comment: I just realised, if one comes across outdated (and harmful) generic setup steps in your old xml files, to then make it possible for everyone in a team to quickly get up to date with their local dev setups and migrated data, without having to manually remove entries from @@tinymce-controlpanel, you just need to add the modern equivalent of that step, as @IdaEbkes pointed out in the edit. I take it purge=True is the default, right? So that should then override the outdated step and change the config.

Comment: I guess a good place to start would be to backup and remove your old xml files, and then run Product.TinyMCE's own generic setup as a starting point, to remove any old config, then export that as a starting point, and then add your custom setup back in (for example linkable custom types etc), minus the old outdated steps?

Comment: If one of your add-ons holds the entries for `ploneimage` and `plonelink`, that would be "wrong",  because it's TinyMCEs job to add them. Maybe you did that  to just have the complete entries in one file. Ideally new entries should be added to the config by the add-on they're related to, that's why `purge=False` is usually the better choice. See updated quest.